# Deleted an Upgrade on Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My game froze on the PS3 when I was playing and when I restarted it an upgrade got lost. i reinstalled the upgrade and got back to my game and when I went to go to the lake view mannor house it was not there. Did I lose the house and everything in it forever, or is there a way to get it back? Did I lose my wife and children and stuff, or did everything get moved?

Answer (score -1):

That happened to me as well on Xbox 360, and I had to rebuild my house, get my wife and kids back. Sorry man, looks like your'e going to have to do what I had to do too.